# Mongo finds the document by query but $pull doesn't do its job

Tags: mongodb

So, I have a document that looks like this:

```
[
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52774aa8036473112ef715eb"),
    "humans" : [
        {
            "name" : "WTF",
            "serviceUsers" : [
                {
                    "username" : "someoneelse",
                    "serviceID" : "abcdefghijklmnop",
                    "service" : "twitter",
                    "onBehalfOf" : "WTF-test"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "password" : "r4fp+7glE/qR3VJuP7Jlvt6pEx4thssi503O8CfFAK1HJEB1F1bIkDHaf+6LHDbm",
    "services" : [
        {
            "twitter" : [ ]
        }
    ],
    "username" : "darthjulian",
    "version" : NumberLong(1)
}
]
```

That array `services`? I want to remove the element `twitter` cause it's empty.

I can query for the document successfully using:

```
> db.users.find({'services.twitter': []}).toArray()
```

So, using the `update` prototype:

```
db.collection.update( { field: <query> }, { $pull: { field: <query> } } );
```

I attempted to `$pull` that element..but the document isn't changed.

My command in the shell is:

```
> db.users.update({'services.twitter': []}, {$pull: {'services.twitter': []}})
```

It seems straight forward, based on the prototype — the query works using a find, but during the $update, nothing happens, not even an error message.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field named in the `$pull` needs to be the array you're looking to modify, so in this case `services`:

```js
db.users.update({'services.twitter': []}, {$pull: {services: { twitter: []}}})
```